# Provisioning did not succeed. Failed to create pages library

Tags: 2013, feature-activation, publishing

I have a client who are trying to create new sub sites in site collections. If they use the publishing site template or if they create a team site and try activate the publishing feature it will always fail with the following error message (Grabbed from ULS):

> Getting Error Message for Exception System.Web.HttpUnhandledException
>   (0x80004005): Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException'
>   was thrown. ---> Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: Provisioning did
>   not succeed. Details: Failed to create the 'Pages' library.
>   OriginalException: Content type
>   '0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF3900242457EFB8B24247815D688C526CD44D'
>   not found in web.

I have checked the site collection and it has the publishing infrastructure activated, I have also tried to force enable the site collection and site features but this has not helped. The content type it is mentioning in the article is the "Article Page" content type. I have checked and it is present on the site I am trying to activate the site feature and in the parent site and is valid as it used for pages in the site collection.

Comment: I am also experiencing this kind of problem. I saw this post but haven't tried it yet - "http://itproafrica.com/technology/sharepoint/sharepoint-2013-failed-to-create-the-pages-library/" - I am not familiar with Stsadm tool. Did you already resolved this? Would you please share if there are any resolution to this problem?

Comment: I have tried that and it didn't seem to help much. It seems that  we are able to force the feature from powershell but the problem is that the client  needs to activate the publishing feature from the UI.

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out I had to roll back to good old stsadm to get this sorted:

stsadm -o activatefeature -name PublishingSite -url  -force
stsadm -o activatefeature -name PublishingWeb -url  -force
stsadm -o activatefeature -name PublishingResources -url  -force

I run all three of the above for the site Collection and then users could activate the publishing feature for sub sites with no issues.